# Why is this method getting called twice?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

The following line of code was calling the `currentPlaybackTime` method on my singleton `MAMusicPlayer` class twice:

```
float trackPosition = MAX(floor([[MAMusicPlayer sharedPlayer] currentPlaybackTime]),0.0f);
[scrubber setValue:trackPosition];
```

Through trial and error I managed to resolve the issue by adjusting the code to:

```
float trackPosition  = floor([[MAMusicPlayer sharedPlayer] currentTrackPosition]);
[scrubber setValue:MAX(trackPosition,0.0f)];
```

However I still do not understand why the first example should call the method twice. Since this is probably fairly fundamental, I thought it best to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MAX(a, b)` is probably a macro defined as `((a > b) ? a : b)`, so when terms are substituted for `a` and `b`, each term is evaluated twice.

Comment: Assuming this is Cocoa MAX is defined a little better then that.     #define MAX(A,B) ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __b : __a; }) You can force it use the worse one by not enabling various extensions though